# Change Class of input element with using id

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, types, submit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change an element’s CSS class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

How can I change the class of `<input type="submit:>` not using the id, just the class in Javascript. I have have tried this (with no luck):

```
function changeClass(){
    document.getElementById("wpsc_buy_button").setAttribute("class", "btn btn-success");
}
```

Comment: This is a dup of a classic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Comment: Not exactly a dup (at least the attempt is different), but a similar question, and the answer can be found there.

Comment: What if i dont want it done on an onclick event and not using any id's, the php generates the id's that why i just wanna concentrate on the class of <input type="classToChange">

Comment: You are using the id in the JS shown ...  `document.getElementById("wpsc_buy_button")`  What do you mean by `How can I change the class of <input type="submit:> not using the id`

Comment: Sorry im a bit of a noob, can i use getElementByClassName instead, maybe that will work?

Answer (score 0):

$('.originalClass').addClass('newClass')

Why would this not work?

you can also do

$('.originalClass').addClass('newClass').removeClass('originalClass');

Comment: 'code'<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

        $('.wpsc_buy_button').addClass('btn btn-success').re

})(jQuery);
</script>'code'

Comment: I tried it both in the header and footer, it is so i can over ride wp ecommerce's classes using twitter bootstrap's.